Why does Excel “EXPAND” function with array as row argument repeat value?
In Excel, =EXPAND(10,5,,10) and =EXPAND(10,{1;2;3;4;5}) produce the same result: a vertical array of the value 10 repeated 5 times.
What does it mean to pass an array to the rows or columns arguments of EXPAND?

Alternative syntax for the EXPAND function
In the EXPAND function, the first argument can be a single value of any type. If the second or third argument is an array of numbers >=1 or TRUE, the result is an array with the structure specified by those array arguments and containing a duplicate of the first argument. If the array contains something else, then the EXPAND function returns an error #VALUE!
Examples on the screenshot below. In my language version, #VALUE! = #ARG!

